# Activity theme appears different than other Activities of the application

Tags: android, android-theme

Hello I am working on an android application. I am showing the `ProgressDialog` when perform the network operation in an application. But theme of `ProgressDialog` appears different in different activities.

```
<activity
    android:name="teemwurk.android.ClockActivity"
     android:label="@string/title_activity_clock"
     android:screenOrientation="portrait"
     android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
</activity>
```

customtheme.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground </item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">60dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:padding">0px</item>
        <item name="android:background">#F3F8FB</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

ClockActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); // requesting to set
                                                        // the custom title
                                                        // bar
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_clock);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.custom_title);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }

    // set the back button on click listener
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.backTextView)).setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

TeemWurkAsyncTask.java

```
public class TeemWurkAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private Context mContext;
    private TaskCompleteListener taskCompleteListener;
    private int method;
    private String TAG = "TeemWurkAsyncTask";

    public TeemWurkAsyncTask(TaskCompleteListener taskCompleteListener, int method, Context mContext) {
        this.taskCompleteListener = taskCompleteListener;
        this.method = method;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // display the progress dialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(mContext.getString(R.string.app_name));
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(mContext.getString(R.string.please_wait));
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }
```

[image]

But I want it should appear like below this `ProgressDialog`

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

Change this..

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
```

to

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@style/AppTheme">
        <item name="newStyle">@style/CustomThemeStyle</item>            
    </style>
    <style name="CustomThemeStyle" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/WindowTitleBackground </item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">60dp</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
    <style name="WindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:padding">0px</item>
        <item name="android:background">#F3F8FB</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**EDIT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <attr name="newStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Comment: Getting an error after doing that 06-02 15:13:30.455: : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Comment: Now getting error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'newStyle'.

Comment: Still getting same error Getting an error after doing that 06-02 15:13:30.455: : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Comment: @Williams add `<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>` in CustomThemeStyle like my edit.

Comment: it is still same issue You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Answer (score 1):

Try this .You should change this

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    ........
</style>
```

to

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:Theme.Holo.Light">
   ........
</style>
```

Comment: Getting an error after doing that 06-02 15:13:30.455: : android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: You cannot combine custom titles with other title features

Comment: @Williams remove all titles attributes and try.

Comment: No I can not remove those items from style because I am using here custom title bar, that's why I added different theme to this activity where progress dialog appears not good

Comment: @Williams but why you added this manually? Holo Theme is taken care of this.

Comment: because to customize the title bar I have to give different style